# adding file upload restriction to the register forum

Tags: php, html, forms

i am making a register form where we enter email address , shop name , photo etc.
i was able to make the upper part of the forum where it contains email address , shop name , telephone number etc.

i would like some help at the part of uploading the picture.
i want a restriction like:

the picture should be not above 50kb and the picture should be in jpg , gif, png & jpeg format.

This is my work(php) :

```
$allowedformat = array("gif" , "jpeg", "jpg" , "png");
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["img_path"]["name"]);
$extension = end($temp);

if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png"))
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000 )
&& in_array($extension, $allowedformat)) {

if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES["img_path"]["tmp_name"]))
{
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["img_path"]["tmp_name"], "shop_image/" .$_FILES["img_path"]["name"]))
{ 
chmod("shop_image/" .$_FILES["img_path"]["name"], 0644);
  echo "the file was successfully uploaded.";
    }else{
      echo "the file could not be uploaded.";
    }
    }else{
      echo "the file was not selected.";
    }
}
?>
```

This is my html work:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<TITLE>register.html</TITLE>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">  

$(document).ready(function(){

// create arrays
var asobi = [
{display: "カラオケ", value: "karaoke" }, 
{display: "ボーリング", value: "bowling" }, 
{display: "ゲームセンタ", value: "game-center" },
{display: "公園", value: "park" },
{display: "パチンコ", value: "pachinko" },
{display: "映画", value: "movie" },
{display: "その他", value: "sonota" }];

 var food = [
 {display: "イタリア", value: "italian" }, 
 {display: "和食", value: "japanese" }, 
 {display: "中華", value: "chinese" },
 {display: "居酒屋", value: "izakaya" },
{display: "ファーストフード", value: "fastfood" }, 
{display: "レストラン", value: "restuarant" }, 
 {display: "洋食", value: "continental" },
 {display: "その他", value: "sonota" }];

  var shopping = [
  {display: "音楽", value: "music" }, 
  {display: "本", value: "book" }, 
  {display: "雑貨", value: "mixed" },
  {display: "お土産", value: "gift" },
  {display: "コンビニ", value: "mart" }, 
  {display: "洋服", value: "clothes" }, 
  {display: "その他", value: "sonota" }];   

var tour = [
{display: "", value: "history" }, 
{display: "?", value: "sonota" }];

var travel = [
{display: "バス", value: "bus" }, 
{display: "タクシー", value: "taxi" }, 
{display: "市電", value: "train" },
{display: "その他", value: "sonota" }];

//If parent option is changed
$("#parent_selection").change(function() {
var parent = $(this).val(); //get option value from parent 

        switch(parent){ //using switch compare selected option and populate       child
          case 'asobi':
            list(asobi);
            break;
          case 'food':
            list(food);
            break;              
          case 'shopping':
            list(shopping);
            break;  
      case 'tour':
    list(tour);
            break;
      case 'travel':
    list(travel);
    break;
        default: //default child option is blank
            $("#child_selection").html('');  
            break;
       }

 });


 //function to populate child select box
 function list(array_list) 
 {
 $("#child_selection").html(""); //reset child options
 $(array_list).each(function (i) { //populate child options 
    $("#child_selection").append("<option  value=\""+array_list[i].value+"\">"+array_list[i].display+"</option>");
 });
 }

 });

 </script>

 </HEAD>
 <BODY bgcolor=white>

 <h1>店舗登録</b></h1><br>

 <FORM action=register.php method=post>

 <hr size="3" color="#a9a9a9" width="100%">

 <!--説明 -->
 ※印がついている項目は必須になります。<br>
 英数字は半角でそれ以外は全角になります。<br>
 住所または電話番号どちらか必須となります。<br>
 <br>
 <br>
 <!-- 入力フィールド　メールアドレス-->
 メールアドレス※
 <input type="text" name="mail" size="20" value="" /><br>
 <br>

 <!-- 入力フィールド　店舗名-->
 店舗名※
 <input type="text" name="name" size="20" value="" /><br>
 <br>

 <!-- 入力フィールド　住所-->
 住所
 <input type="text" name="address" size="30" value="" /><br>
 <br>

 <!-- 入力フィールド　電話番号-->
 電話番号
 <input type="text" name="telephone" size="20" value="" /><br>
 <br>

 <!-- 入力フィールド　カテゴリ・サブカテゴリ-->
 Category : <select name="parent_selection" id="parent_selection">
 <option value="">-- Please Select --</option>
 <option value="asobi">遊び</option>
 <option value="food">グルメ</option>
 <option value="shopping">ショッピング</option>
 <option value="tour">観光</option>
 <option value="travel">交通</option>
 </select>
 <select name="child_selection" id="child_selection">
 </select>
 <select name="child_selection" id="child_selection">
 </select>
 <br>
 <br>
 画像：<br />
<input type="file" name="img_path" size="30" /><br />
<br />

<br><br><INPUT type=submit value="送信"  style="position: absolute; left: 30%;      top: 50%; width: 5%  "/ >
</FORM>
</div>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

From the if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES["img_path"]["tmp_name"])) .....
i was able to upload the picture.
but when i added the restrictions ( the upper part with ifs) , i was not able to find the picture.
There was no syntax error but i was not able to find the picture in the folder [ shop_image ] when i tested 
& while testing i was able to submit the txt file also which they should get error if its uploaded as i need only picture format.
&& im really not sure if this programming is correct or not.
If there is a easier way , please let me know.

could you please help me out.
Thankyou

Comment: make sure to turn on error reporting when debugging

Comment: Make sure you're running your script from the root of your server since you're using `shop_image/` as the upload folder. Otherwise, use something like `../shop_image/` depending on the script's location, and make sure the folder's permissions are correctly set to write to. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything.

Comment: Plus this `["img_path"]` should match. You're using `file` and `img_path` be consistent; keep them all the same and it WILL work.

Comment: I deleted my answer, since I was not able to figure out why you are unable to use my working code with yours. Good luck with that.